# Static class and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: arrays, wpf, data-binding, binding, interface

I have a TextBlock bound to a static string field of a static class. Now, when I change the value of that field (not using the mentioned TextBlock, but another way), the TextBlock's content does not change.
I know that there's an interface INotifyPropertyChanged, which can be used in such situations. Unfortunately my class is static (it contains information which are to be shared across my whole application), so it cannot implement interfaces.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, but how can I add INotifyPropertyChanged to my STATIC class?

Comment: You don't "add INotifyPropertyChanged". Instead, you declare a `public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged`. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties.